# Xamarin Forms: PDF does not work on Android Platform

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Based off this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=windows
I have tried to display the PDF listed here:
https://www.adobe.com/support/products/enterprise/knowledgecenter/media/c4611_sample_explain.pdf

I have no issues on iOS, but on Android this does not seems to work.
Here is the specific code, its not much really,

```
        {
            var browser = new WebView();            
            browser.Source = "https://www.adobe.com/support/products/enterprise/knowledgecenter/media/c4611_sample_explain.pdf";            
            Content = browser;
        }
```

I thought we longer needed PDFJs to make PDFs work on Android platform.
Is that still true?

Comment: not all Android devices have native PDF support.  Have you tried just opening that url in Chrome to see what happens?

Comment: the device I am testing on, when a PDF is accessed via browser. , it opens the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google PDF Viewer to read your pdf online. first of all, create a custom webview in PCL folder.

```
   public class MyWebview:WebView
    {
    }
```

Then used it in the `WebPage.cs`

```
  public class WebPage : ContentPage
    {
        public WebPage()
        {
            var browser = new MyWebview();
           
            Content = browser;
        }
    }
```

Create a custom renderer for your webview in android folder.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(WorkingWithWebview.MyWebview), typeof(MyWebViewRenderer))]
namespace WorkingWithWebview.Android
{
   public class MyWebViewRenderer:WebViewRenderer
    {
        Context _context;

        public MyWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            var settings=Control.Settings;
            settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            settings.SetPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.On);

            Control.SetWebViewClient(new MyWebviewClient());

           

                  string pdf = "https://www.adobe.com/support/products/enterprise/knowledgecenter/media/c4611_sample_explain.pdf";
            Control.LoadUrl("https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
        }
    }

    internal class MyWebviewClient : WebViewClient
    {
        public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(global::Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is running GIF.

[image]

Comment: Thanks . I have this solution implemented. But why claim that PDF works in WebView? for Both Android and iOS?

 - Documents – Because WebView is implemented using native components on each platform, WebView is capable of showing documents that are viewable on each platform.
That means that PDF files work on iOS and Android.

Comment: That means Local PDF file, such as in Assets folder or external local stroage.

Comment: @leon-lu-msft  where in the documentation it says Local? granted it does not say remote either, but it would be helpful that if it is clarified.

Comment: This aricle do not contains how to achieve the PDF files display, you can use PDF Viewer or pdf.js to display the remote pdf or local pdf. According to my understanding, this article mean webview could show PDF, but it cannot be showed in Native webview in xamarin Forms, If you think this article is not clear or wrong, you can  take a feedback for this page in this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=windows#related-links